# Interfacing DS1307 RTC with PIC16f882

Tags: microcontroller, pic, rtc

I am trying to interface DS1307 RTC with the MCU mentioned. I want to make a lifetime timer which tells the time this project has worked in field, and display this timer on an LCD.

I am new to microcontrollers but using LCD and I2C libraries already built-in in the MikroC pro for PIC compiler will I hope save me from low-level programming.

Now if I understand correctly, the steps to write or read something from the RTC would be:

```
1) I2C_Start();
2) I2C_Write(DS1307_Address);
3) I2C_Write(Register Address);
4) I2C_Write(Data to be written);
5) I2C_Stop();
```

and for reading:

```
1) I2C_Start();
2) I2C_Write(DS1307_Address);
3) I2C_Write(Register Address);
4) I2C_Repeated_Start();
5) I2C_Write(DS1307_Address);
6) I2C_Rd();
7) I2C_Stop();
```

My issue is that what will the `DS1307_Address` be, if it is the only device on the Bus?

My approach will be to set the BIT7 of 00h or `CH` bit of the DS1307 low whenever the device is running, and set it high just before shutting down. I do not want the RTC to count the project off time as well. Is this approach feasible?

My schematic is as following:

[image]

Comment: The addresses of I2C devices are usually given in their datasheet.

Comment: Your read sequence needs another step between 3 and 4 - an "I2C Restart".

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have gone through the datasheet multiple times, can't seem to find it. Can you have a look please:
http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1307.pdf

Comment: @brhans Thank you brhans, I will update my question and my code.

Comment: Page 12. Reading datasheets is one of the *most essential* skills for one dealing with electronics. With assistance of Ctrl-F it takes like 20 seconds.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you Eugene, should have tried Ctrl-F, will remember this tip next time.

Comment: @brhans There seems to be no Restart() function in the MikroC library. Will Start() and Stop() again do the same function correctly?

Comment: There is a `I2C_Repeated_Start` function. Tak a look at the examples on [this page](http://download.mikroe.com/documents/compilers/mikroc/pic/help/i2c_library.htm)

Comment: @EugeneSh. your 20s diagnostics is pretty much spot-on ;-) .

Comment: @EugeneSh. I want to just edit the 7th bit from the Seconds register, not altering the seconds in it. How can it be possible when I am supposed to write a whole byte every single time like:
I2C1_Wr(0x80) and I2C1_Wr(0x00)

Comment: You can't modify a single bit. You need to read, mask, write. But I can see a small problem here. The seconds can be updated (not more than once, though, but still) during this sequence, so you will loose one second. If you don't really care about the slowly accumulated error, you can ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [data sheet](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1307.pdf), page 12:

> The  slave  address  byte  contains  the  7-bit  DS1307 address, which is 1101000, followed by the direction bit (R/W), which for a write is 0.

So the address you're looking for is **1101000**.